# Why are Luciole's and StopMotion's screenshots inverted in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, screenshot

Using 12.04 beta and navigating in the Ubuntu Software Center, I noticed that Luciole has StopMotion's screenshot, and StopMotion has Luciole's screenshot.

However, on screenshots.debian.net, it looks like everything is in order:

http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/package/luciole

http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/package/stopmotion

Any idea why?

Comment: Appears to be a bug

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I didn't know it was a bug, I just thought it was an error on the website at the beginning, that's why I asked first.
Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug, I tried to reproduce it but failed. If you can reproduce it I would love to get steps how to do that so that the devs can work on fixing this bug.

Comment: This didn't revert went I unistalled both apps. I don't really know how to reproduce this.